# How to use apache to redirect to docker container

Tags: apache, ubuntu, docker, tornado

I have two docker containers running Tornado applications, named `app1` and `app2` on a Ubuntu VM. The VM has a domain name `ubuntu.somesite.com`. I can access one of them with docker port forwarding at `ubuntu.somesite.com:8080`. Instead I want both apps to be accessible at `ubuntu.somesite.com/app1` and `ubuntu.somesite.com/app2`. What would be the best way to accomplish this? I tried using apache virtual hosts but didn't get very far.

Comment: Good tutorial if you also want to use HTTPS, see: https://codeburst.io/http-server-on-docker-with-https-7b5468f72874

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to expose both docker containers on the host network, of course on two different ports (let's say 8080 and 8081).

Than you need a reverse proxy in your host. Apache 2.4 is one possible choice.
You could use a virtualhost like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName ubuntu.somesite.com

  <Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
  </Location>

  ProxyPass /app1 http://127.0.0.1:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse /app1 http://127.0.0.1:8080/

  ProxyPass /app2/ http://127.0.0.1:8081/
  ProxyPassReverse /app2/ http://127.0.0.1:8081/
</VirtualHost>
```

Please note that this config will not work with apache 2.2 or older.

Comment: Does this expose `ubuntu.somesite.com:8080` and `:8081` to the outside? If so, is there a way not to make it so?

Comment: they're exposed in the host network. If you have a firewall your services won't be reachable on that port. If you want to avoid port mapping at all, you can use a reverse proxy which is itself dockerized, and expose only the proxy to the host network.

Comment: After doing this, in case you get an error saying `Invalid command 'ProxyPass'`, just run `sudo a2enmod proxy_http` and it should start working

Comment: I am running sonar on the docker. My apache (service on centOS) can't find the files. I tested it with `<Location>` and without `<Location>`. My error: `AH00128: File does not exist: GET /sonarqube/js/main.m.c5b6e957.js`. What do I need to configure?

Comment: and don't forget  to add this line to etc hosts -     127.0.0.1  ubuntu.somesite.com